# CSS arrow icon borders render differently in different browsers

Tags: css, border

I'm trying to build arrow icons with the [css triangles method](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/).

I built this one in Chrome v14 - OSX, and it works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/olegmil/2cXZw/21/

But it looks very different in any other browser:

[image: chrome-osx][image: ff6-osx][image: opera-osx]
[image: ff6-win][image: ie8]

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Different rendering engines render different :P

Comment: How does it look different and it what browsers are you referring to specifically..

Comment: This looks the same to me in Chrome, FF, IE... but I don't own a Mac.

Comment: images added (300% zoom)

Comment: Dude those look close enough to me

Comment: why not use a `>` character and try to find a suitable font.  Take a look here (http://www.google.com/webfonts) for even more font choices.  It seems like you are reinventing the wheel for no gain. especially at those small sizes.

Comment: I've decided to create a font with all pixel icons i need: http://fontstruct.com/fontstructions/show/wuwacorp
and to use it with @fontface.
the markup im much better now. Thank you all for help!

Comment: @olegmil While that will have better support, the trade off will also be a slower load time and possible FOUT. Overall, I'd say a good solution, but just making sure you're aware.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which browsers I'd hazard a guess at looking at conditional stylesheets if it is by chance ie

Just google conditional stylesheets or visit [this link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

You should utilize the transparent property instead of explicitly setting the background colors. This is happening because you're trying to fill in a small block with a background which is causing some issues.

I've forked your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JXXZa/

That has all the necessary changes and should display better in all browsers.

Comment: It does look very clean, but your shape now differs from his original. Notice the tail ends.

Comment: Yes, I know the shape is different. but it is the easiest solution for cross browser compatibility. The issue with the shape presented is as shown in the examples. Some browsers will render it with a hard pixel shape, while others will not, which will lead to inconsistencies with the display of it as 'rounding' (of sorts) takes place.